# Notice: Undefined index: host in White Screen of Death

Tags: php, wordpress, host

I have tested plugins & checked PHP versions. So far I've not been able to fix the issue(s):

```
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 461
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 462
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 462
Notice: Undefined index: scheme in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 482
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 461
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 461
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 463
Notice: Undefined index: host in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 465
Notice: Undefined index: scheme in /home/f2drufxgri7b/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 482
```

Comment: provide some code. not only the errors

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by Updating the Wordpress manually and using PHP 5.6 to access the WPAdmin. Later I updated to latest PHP version and updated all Plugins from WP Admin.

It seems that the error was due to PHP, Wordpress and Plugins Updates wish created the WhiteScreen of Death.

I stronlgly reccomend Updating PHP and Wordpress versions before migrating the website.